# Disable Save As In A Batch Of Excel Files

Tags: vba, excel

I've been researching how to disable "Save As" in Excel and it seems possible. I have a macro that loops through a bunch of Excel files making changes. In that macro I would like to disable "Save As" for all of the files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using application object. You just add this lines to the code that loops in every file or workbook so it disable "save as" for each one :

```
Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save As...").Enabled = False 
Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save").Enabled = False
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Hello. I can but I know the code works because i've used it before. I'm just making improvements to my macro I have for work.

Comment: @GaryDorman I see, did you put it inside the loop after it opens every file ?, did it show any errors ?

Comment: Hello. Yes i put it inside the loop and it didn't show any errors.

Comment: @GaryDorman and you did it after it opened file ?, it's "save as..." still available ?

Comment: Yes I placed the code right before I did a save on the file to keep my other changes. I also tried just using the first line you gave me as I don't want to disable save. Just save as.

Comment: Both Save and Save as were still available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128277/discussion-between-jsanchezs-and-gary-dorman).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```